# Computer Freezes At Login "Welcome"

Tags: freeze

I know this probably isn't the right forum to be posting this in, but I don't have an account on any other tech support website...

So my computer froze when I tried to log into my account.  It took a really long time at the "Welcome" screen with the blue wheel, and then the screen went blue and just the mouse was there.  Nothing else worked; no task manager, etc.  So I started up in Safe Mode and went to msconfig->General->Selective Startup->Uncheck "Load Startup Items"->Services->Hide All Microsoft Services->Disable All->Ok->Restarted Computer

This time, I was able to log in to my account, but everything loads incredibly slowly, and if the computer lags it will freeze.  Does anyone know how to fix this/what's going on? :(  I'd like to get back to prepping for the CCC =\

Comment: I am assuming you are on windows. A few items to look at - 1) Too many services might be running on load, msconfig and turn off most of them. 2) your drive in which windows is installed, might be 75% or more full? 3) If second one is not the case, then it could be your RAM/motherboard which is creating problem. 4) Or maybe you have installed something lately which is causing this trouble (I wonder antivirus - blah, I hate them to death). :) 5) If your current windows version has been there in your computer/laptop for over an year or two then try and get a fresh install.. :) Hope it helps..

Comment: 1) I'll try this option first, but I'm pretty sure I already disabled all non-microsoft services on startup.  2) Don't know what this means =\.  3) My computer is making this weird clicking noise.. 4) Haven't installed anything recently 5) I think this will probably be my last resort.

Comment: 2) This is your drive where your windows is installed on your system. This might be C drive wherein you will see folders called "Windows, Program files" etc.. This drive could be full. Say if it is allocated around 10GB then it might be around 8-8.5GB or more..

Comment: Are you saying you are getting a beep sound on start? If so then it is RAM issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be full.  I don't have a lot of stuff (I don't download much).  It's not a beeping sound.  It clicks 3 times every few seconds when I try to do something like open the start menu